# Issue regarding the Attribute Names

Tags: wcf, sharepoint

Xml Document

I am having a problem regarding the xml attribute names coming from sharepoint which contains the attributes names like description0,ows_x0020_long_desc coming in the xmldoc

```
    <z:row ows_LinkFilename="Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
   ows_Title="Aerospace" 
   ows_ContentType="Image" 
   ows__ModerationStatus="0" 
   ows_PreviewOnForm="Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
   ows_ThumbnailOnForm="Technology Experience/Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
   ows_Modified="2011-12-07 12:02:34" 
   ows_Editor="1073741823;#System Account" 
   ows_Description0="Honeywell's SmartPath® Ground-Based Augmentation System (GBAS), which offers airports improved efficiency and capacity, greater navigational accuracy, and fewer weather-related delays." 
   ows_ID="28" 
   ows_Created="2011-12-02 11:26:01" 
   ows_Author="1073741823;#System Account" 
   ows_FileSizeDisplay="6091" 
   ows_Mode="Energy" 
   ows_Solution="Business" 
   ows_Long_x0020_Desc="Honeywell's SmartTraffic™ and IntuVue® 3-D Weather Radar technologies make the skies safer and enable pilots to more efficiently route flights. SmartTraffic ." 
   ows_Brief_x0020_Desc="Honeywell's Required Navigation Performance (RNP) capabilities enable aircraft to fly more precise approaches through tight corridors and congested airports, leading to fewer delays." 
   ows_Tags="True" 
   ows__Level="1" 
   ows_UniqueId="28;#{928FDA3E-94FA-47A5-A9AD-B5D98C12C18C}" 
   ows_FSObjType="28;#0" 
   ows_Created_x0020_Date="28;#2011-12-02 11:26:01" 
   ows_ProgId="28;#" 
   ows_FileRef="28;#Technology Experience/Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
   ows_DocIcon="jpg" 
   ows_MetaInfo="28;#Solution:SW|Business vti_thumbnailexists:BW|true vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.4762 Category:SW|Enter Choice #1 Description0:LW|Honeywell's SmartPath® Ground-Based Augmentation System (GBAS), which offers airports improved efficiency and capacity, greater navigational accuracy, and fewer weather-related delays. vti_stickycachedpluggableparserprops:VX|wic_XResolution Subject vti_lastheight vti_title vti_lastwidth wic_YResolution oisimg_imageparsedversion vti_lastwidth:IW|294 vti_author:SR|SHAREPOINT\\system vti_previewexists:BW|true vti_modifiedby:SR|SHAREPOINT\\system Long Desc:LW|Honeywell's SmartTraffic™ and IntuVue® 3-D Weather Radar technologies make the skies safer and enable pilots to more efficiently route flights. SmartTraffic . Keywords:LW| vti_foldersubfolderitemcount:IR|0 vti_lastheight:IW|172 ContentTypeId:SW|0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F21400623D4FCEEB2ADC4EA8269BF873F0BB6F _Author:SW| vti_title:SW|Aerospace wic_System_Copyright:SW| Mode:SW|Energy Tags:SW|True wic_YResolution:DW|96.0000000000000 oisimg_imageparsedversion:IW|4 Brief Desc:LW|Honeywell's Required Navigation Performance (RNP) capabilities enable aircraft to fly more precise approaches through tight corridors and congested airports, leading to fewer delays. _Comments:LW| wic_XResolution:DW|96.0000000000000 Subject:SW|Aerospace vti_folderitemcount:IR|0" 
   ows_Last_x0020_Modified="28;#2011-12-07 12:02:34" 
   ows_owshiddenversion="6" 
   ows_FileLeafRef="28;#Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
   ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" 
   xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
```

Could you please tell the solution for this.

Comment: so what is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint when returning data in xml will always use this fromat.

- Field names will be prepended by ows_
- Internal names of field will be used not display names.
- Internal field names in SharePoint contain unicode equivalents for special characters
  e.g. if you create a field with name 'Field Name' from SharePoint UI,
      SharePoint will create internal name as 'Field_x0020_Name'
      where 0020 is unicode representation of space.

  If fields are created by code or feature however you can specify your own  internal and display names.

So if you are parsing such xml you will have to code remembering these rules.

---

SharePoint does not add *x0020* escape sequence in field's internal name unless there is a space in the display name while creating the field from UI.
Also once the  field is created, changing the display name has no effect on the internal name of a field.
So if you create a field 'Long Desc' from UI and the later change the name to 'LongDesc', the internal name will still be Long_x0020_Desc.

Comment: Good answer. You should also mention that x0020 is simply the unicode representation of the space character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20/index.htm

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out , I wrote hexadecimal by mistake instead of unicode so corrected it