# Issue regarding the attributes in sharepoint

Tags: wcf, sharepoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issue regarding the Attribute Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411414/issue-regarding-the-attribute-names)

Can I change the attribute Names as the column i have specified in Sharepoint UI is having no space.It is "longdesc",still it is showing ows_x0020_long_desc.

```
     <z:row 
        ows_LinkFilename="Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
        ows_Title="Aerospace" 
        ows_ContentType="Image" 
        ows__ModerationStatus="0" 
        ows_PreviewOnForm="Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
        ows_ThumbnailOnForm="Technology Experience/Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
        ows_Modified="2011-12-07 12:02:34" 
        ows_Editor="1073741823;#System Account" 
        ows_Description0="Honeywell's SmartPath® Ground-Based Augmentation System (GBAS), which offers airports improved efficiency and capacity, greater navigational accuracy, and fewer weather-related delays." 
        ows_ID="28" 
        ows_Created="2011-12-02 11:26:01" 
        ows_Author="1073741823;#System Account" 
        ows_FileSizeDisplay="6091" 
        ows_Mode="Energy" 
        ows_Solution="Business" 
        ows_Long_x0020_Desc="Honeywell's SmartTraffic™ and IntuVue® 3-D Weather Radar technologies make the skies safer and enable pilots to more efficiently route flights. SmartTraffic" 
        ows_Brief_x0020_Desc="Honeywell's Required Navigation Performance (RNP) capabilities enable aircraft to fly more precise approaches through tight corridors and congested airports, leading to fewer delays." 
        ows_Tags="True" 
        ows__Level="1" 
        ows_UniqueId="28;#{928FDA3E-94FA-47A5-A9AD-B5D98C12C18C}" 
        ows_FSObjType="28;#0" 
        ows_Created_x0020_Date="28;#2011-12-02 11:26:01" 
        ows_ProgId="28;#" 
        ows_FileRef="28;#Technology Experience/Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
        ows_DocIcon="jpg" 
        ows_MetaInfo="28;#Solution:SW|Business vti_thumbnailexists:BW|true vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.4762 Category:SW|Enter Choice #1 Description0:LW|Honeywell's SmartPath® Ground-Based Augmentation System (GBAS), which offers airports improved efficiency and capacity, greater navigational accuracy, and fewer weather-related delays. vti_stickycachedpluggableparserprops:VX|wic_XResolution Subject vti_lastheight vti_title vti_lastwidth wic_YResolution oisimg_imageparsedversion vti_lastwidth:IW|294 vti_author:SR|SHAREPOINT\\system vti_previewexists:BW|true vti_modifiedby:SR|SHAREPOINT\\system Long Desc:LW|Honeywell's SmartTraffic™ and IntuVue® 3-D Weather Radar technologies make the skies safer and enable pilots to more efficiently route flights. SmartTraffic . Keywords:LW| vti_foldersubfolderitemcount:IR|0 vti_lastheight:IW|172 ContentTypeId:SW|0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F21400623D4FCEEB2ADC4EA8269BF873F0BB6F _Author:SW| vti_title:SW|Aerospace wic_System_Copyright:SW| Mode:SW|Energy Tags:SW|True wic_YResolution:DW|96.0000000000000 oisimg_imageparsedversion:IW|4 Brief Desc:LW|Honeywell's Required Navigation Performance (RNP) capabilities enable aircraft to fly more precise approaches through tight corridors and congested airports, leading to fewer delays. _Comments:LW| wic_XResolution:DW|96.0000000000000 Subject:SW|Aerospace vti_folderitemcount:IR|0" 
        ows_Last_x0020_Modified="28;#2011-12-07 12:02:34" 
        ows_owshiddenversion="6" 
        ows_FileLeafRef="28;#Aerospace Energy.jpg" 
        ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" 
    xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
```

Can you please suggest a solution for removing the _x0020 from the attribute name.

Comment: you already posted this question here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411414/issue-regarding-the-attribute-names

and you also got an answer